# SSRS Report appears with empty tablix on the last page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Dears,
I developed the report with some of the groups and everything working well but when executing it always get empty tablix on the last page like the below image

[Empty Tablix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IftHI.jpg)

I have tried many solutions but without a real solution yet

Comment: I tried the below code:
           =iif(CountRows("DataSet1") > 0, true, false)

and the empty tablix has been disappeared but the pagination also disappeared on the last page of the report !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you mentioned is true just make sure to add the footer in the first and last page from footer properties